# API AspNet Core com EntityFramework Core - Entiades desconectadas

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp-net-core

Meu cenário é o seguinte: Tenho uma API em AspNet core que utiliza o EntityFramework para acesso a dados (banco postgree).

Quando recebo o conteúdo em Json pela API (Put) e preciso atualizar o modelo recebido no banco de dados eu tenho problema com as entidades relacionadas.

Observe o seguinte Json recebido do modelo *Pedido*:

```
{
   "pedidoNumero": 0,
   "pessoaId": 5,
   "pessoa"{
       "id": 5,
       "nome": "Teste",
       "cidadeId: 1,
       "cidade": {
            "id": 1,
            "nome": "Cidade teste",
        },
   },
   pedidoItens:[
       {
           "produtoId": 1,
           "quantidade" 5,
           "total": 10.00,
       },
       {
           "produtoId": 1,
           "quantidade" 5,
           "total": 10.00,
       }]
}
```

Eu busco o *Pedido* pelo *Id* e faço a chamada para o entity atualizar da seguinte forma:

```
var pedidoExistente = _context.Pedido.Find(pedidoAtualizado.Id);
_context.Entry(pedidoExistente).CurrentValues.SetValues(pedidoAtualizado);
```

O problema nesse cenário é que o Entity tenta inserir a *Pessoa* e a *Cidade* relacionada a *Pessoa*

Eu poderia manipular o objeto manualmente dando um *Attach* na *Pessoa* e 
na *Cidade*, contudo meu objetivo é fazer que o procedimento de atualização funcione de forma genérica, com isso o modelo a ser atualizado pode ter várias e/ou nenhuma entidade relacionada.

Minha intenção é: Fazer a atualização do pedido de forma que o Entity já reconheça as entidades relacionadas existentes e não atualize.

Existe alguma forma ou solução para a questão?

*Ps. Os códigos que postei acima foi feito para exemplo, não é a forma real que utilizo.*

Comment: Você deve observar o mapeamento do seu contexto, para que seja possivel altera apenas umas das tabelas: exemplo:
var pedidoExistente  = _mapper.Map<PedidoViewModel>(await _pedidoRepository.ObterPorID(id));

Comment: e provável que o _context.Pedido.Find está mapeando mais tabelas

Comment: Sim, o contexto está mapeado para várias tabelas, onde algumas devem ser atualizadas junto com o "pai" e outras são apenas tabelas relacionadas que não podem ser atualizadas (caso da pessoa). Minha intenção é achar um Partner e ou uma solução já existente no EF.

Answer (score 1):

> ...CurrentValues.SetValues can take any object and maps property
>   values to the attached entity based on the property name. If the
>   property names in your model are different from the names in the
>   entity you can't use this method and must assign the values one by
>   one.

Usando esta forma de atualização com `CurrentValues.SetValues` você precisa ter sua propriedades mapeadas com os mesmos nomes, assim é possível fazer atualização no models de *Pessoa* e *Cidade* como comentou.

[Aqui tem uma resposta que pode ser útil neste caso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176014/how-to-add-update-child-entities-when-updating-a-parent-entity-in-ef)

Comment: Xará, eu agradeço a resposta. Eu já faço a mesma coisa que da resposta do artigo que você me passou. Aparentemente não tem mágica. Todo o processo deve ser realizado manualmente mesmo.